Autowire EntityManager without Entity class in Symfony 6.4 - Problem and solution
For the modernisation of a legacy code base I want to retrieve page contents from a database without relying on proper entity classes. Since the database structure itself requires redesign, I  want to execute the queries found in the legacy code base and do things properly after the initial rewrite phase.
Following the recommended Symfony steps, I provided a condition service and implemented the service lookup in the code.
But I ended up with the following HTTP 500 Internal Server Error message:
Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\PageRepository": argument "$entityClass" of method "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepositoryProxy::__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.

To do so, I've created a PageRepository class, using the following code:
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;

class PageRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function findPageByUri(string $uri): array
    {
        $db = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE url LIKE :uri';

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue('uri', $uri);
        $resultSet = $stmt->executeQuery();

        if (false === ($result = $resultSet->fetchAssociative())) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('Page "%s" was not found', $uri));
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

This repository is injected into a PageLookupService class with the following code:
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service;

use App\Repository\PageRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Attribute\AsRoutingConditionService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

#[AsRoutingConditionService(alias: 'lookup_service')]
class PageLookupService
{
    private UrlGeneratorInterface $router;
    private PageRepository $pageRepository;
    public function __construct(
        UrlGeneratorInterface $router,
        PageRepository $pageRepository
    ) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    public function lookup(Request $request): array
    {
        $uri = $request->getPathInfo();
        return $this->pageRepository->findPageByUri($uri);
    }

    // To trigger a not found exception, return true for route lookups
    public function doesPageExists(Request $request): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}

My page controller has the following code:
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/{slug}', name: 'page', condition: "service('lookup_service').doesPageExists(request)")]
    public function page(PageLookupService $lookupService, Request $request): Response
    {
        $page = $lookupService->lookup($request);
        return $this->render('page.html.twig', [
            'title' => $page['title'],
            'contents' => $page['contents'],
        ]);
    }
}

Solution I found
Since I was extending the ServiceEntityRepository, I should have injected the entity class name into its constructor, which I hadn't created yet. In order to use the db connection directly, I needed to remove the ServiceEntityRepository extension and inject the EntityManagerInterface directly in this class.
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class PageRepository
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
    public function findPageByUri(string $uri): array
    {
        $db = $this->entityManager->getConnection();
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE url LIKE :uri';

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue('uri', $uri);
        $resultSet = $stmt->executeQuery();

        if (false === ($result = $resultSet->fetchAssociative())) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('Page "%s" was not found', $uri));
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

Because I was not able to find this particular error on the internet, I thought it might be useful to share it here. Let me know if there's an easier way to accommodate this quick retrieval of data without the overhead of heaving entities.
CREDITS: A big shout-out to Stefan Koopmanschap for guiding me towards this solution!
